# Закрытие файла, Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно закрыть определенный файл в Python 3.7;

Пытался решить эту проблему с помощью модуля `os`, должной информации не нашел. А должно все выглядеть так:

```py
import os, time
a = input('Программа: ')
os.startfile(a)
time.sleep(10)
#Тут код, который закрывает программу a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не закрытие файла.
Закрытие файла это:

```
...
file.close()
```

Для того что вы хотите сделать можно использовать такой код (Windows):

```
import os, time
a = input('Программа: ')
os.startfile(a)
time.sleep(10)
os.system(f"taskkill /IM {a} /F")
```